# Why wont my dynamic row displayed centered

Tags: css, asp.net, flexbox

I add these panels dynamically. They tile correctly but there is a margin on the right side still  when i want it all centered. Here is a sample of the code.

```
<style>
    .row {
        display:  flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
       align-content: center;
       margin:auto;
       flex-grow:inherit;


    }
</style>

<div>
    <h1 style="text-align: center;">Schedule an Appointment</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-info " style="margin-left: 10%; margin-right: 
       10%;"  runat="server">
    <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">Step 1: Click on A Picture to Select a 
             Theripist</h3>
    </div>

        <asp:Panel class="row container-fluid " style="text-align:center;" 
         ID="PicturePanel" runat="server" Height="100%" Width="100%" 
          HorizontalAlign="Center">
        </asp:Panel>
    </div>
```

Comment: Are you trying to center the panel in the middle of the screen?

Comment: I don't know aspx, but is this `HorizontalAlign="Center"` meant to be `vertical-align: middle;` ?

Comment: Can you put together a jsfiddle or codepen with the resulting markup that comes from rendering the ASP page?